# JAVA_HOME in bashrc

Tags: java, maven

i got this warning when i checked `mvn -version`

```
Warning: JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set.
Apache Maven 3.0.5
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.6.0_37, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.19.0-25-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

i checked java

```
which java 
/usr/bin/java
```

i checked maven

```
which mvn
/usr/bin/mvn
```

what should i write in bashrc for java and maven?

Comment: Does Maven still work?

Comment: how can i checked it ? i'm new in both

Comment: As in, does Maven actually *break* because of this?  Also, why are you using Java 6?

Comment: i know it's old but i imported project using jdk6 i want to try it first

Comment: I think that you do not only need to set JAVA_HOME, but you should add this environment variable to your path variable too

Comment: Check this: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-java_home-path-variable/  . Your JAVA_HOME should point to jdk not jre

Comment: thanks for link , i checked /usr folder but didn't find and java folder

Comment: By default you have open jdk. You can download Oracle's JAVA and follow the instructions of the site. It depends which JAVA distribution you want

Comment: you mean i need to install oracle-java-6 beside jdk6 ?

Comment: No. If you already have it just make JAVA_HOME point to this jdk

Comment: thanks i'm now confusing for JAVA_HOME when i execute which java i got it in /usr/bin and when i checked path of openjdk6 i got it in /usr/lib/jvm/openjdk6 which i will choose ?

Comment: why it read jre path , i want jdk not jre ?

Comment: Run  alternatives --config java to pick the Java version you want to use as default.

Answer (score 8):

It seems that you do not have a Java JDK (Java Development Kit) installed, if you try run the following command you:

```
javac -version
```

probably you will get the following:

```
The program 'javac' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jdk
 * ecj
 * gcj-4.6-jdk
 * gcj-4.7-jdk
 * openjdk-7-jdk
 * openjdk-6-jdk
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

So, you have to run the following command will install the OpenJDK version of the Java JDK:

```
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set the JAVA_HOME environment variable by adding the following to your .bashrc file:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64
```

Then force a reload of the .bashrc script by executing the following:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: i installed mvn using sudo apt-get install mvn so is this path for mvn too ?

Comment: That's actually pointing to the JRE, maven compiler will probably not work

Comment: It will depend on where everything is installed on your OS, but I've edited the answer to remove the jre directory on the end.

Comment: @Beginnier type `echo $JAVA_HOME` to verify if you've set it properly. If you see the path it's good, if you see nothing it is not set.

Comment: yes, i checked it by echo $JAVA_HOME got nothing what should i do ?

Comment: You need to reload the .bashrc script. See edited answer above.

Comment: For reference: another way to load the .bashrc script is just to open a new terminal window (or relogin with ssh etc...)

Comment: Try typing `export JAVA_HOME=what/ever/it/is` in the terminal. This will only set it for the current session (if you close it it's gone). Then do `echo $JAVA_HOME` to see if it's set then.

Comment: Thanks it worked after forcing , last thing about maven i installed it how can i find path of it ?

Comment: You could try: sudo find / -name mvn

Comment: Works great, I use `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default` and PATH `/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin`.

Answer (score 4):

Export the `JAVA_HOME` variable.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java/home
```

Depending on your installation, you can also use `java_home` with the version.

```
JAVA_VERSION=1.7
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v $JAVA_VERSION)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also the option to use dynamic env manager like

http://www.jenv.be/

there the setup is

```
$ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.jenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
$ echo 'eval "$(jenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

and you can toggle between versions

```
$ jenv versions
  system
  oracle64-1.6.0.39
* oracle64-1.7.0.11 (set by /Users/hikage/.jenv/version)
```

You can locate java by doing

```
$ which java
/usr/bin/java
$ ll /usr/bin/java
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  74 Oct 26 23:27 /usr/bin/java@ -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java
```

Comment: how can i know where i installed java ?

Answer (score -4):

Suggest setting the environment variable JAVA_HOME.